# C#/C++ multiple apps pes solution

Tags: c#, c++

How can I link multiple applications found within the same solution? Each app has a different objective, yet the output of each is determined by the input of the previous

Comment: Why do you want to link multiple **applications** and not just object modules? If you want two applications to execute one after another, you can just write a batch/shell file.

Comment: @Vlad: Every application has its own function, and each one will run according to the other apps, well not everyone, some of them will be working alone, yet I don`t want to have many exe files.

Comment: Well, if you've got to C++ applications linked together, which of the two `main` functions you would like to be executed? The linker would be unable to decide.

Comment: one will be the main which will load all the others, and will call the ones that need to be excuted at specific time only.

Comment: I am not aware of such a solution. A simple way would be to have one more executable (perhaps a script), which would start the others according to some logic. Is there something speaking against, beside of having all of them in one file?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would be to have each application write it's results to the standard output. This would allow any other application to execute it, and read it's results. By using this setup any language that can read from the standard output will be capable of running the application and reading it's result.

This is a very common solution when language interop is a priority.